# How to move files between two Amazon S3 Buckets using boto with a signed URL?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to copy a key from an S3 bucket I don't own into a bucket I do. To access the key in the external bucket I have a signed URL. How can I copy the key using Boto 3?

I know I can use [`S3.Client.copy`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) to move a key, like

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

Is there a way to call this function using the parameters from the signed URL?

The URL contains the query parameters

```
X-Amz-Security-Token
X-Amz-Algorithm
X-Amz-Date
X-Amz-SignedHeaders
X-Amz-Expires
X-Amz-Credential
X-Amz-Signature
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible. You may have to download the object and upload it.

Comment: It looks like this is not possible. Under the hood, the copy is implemented using a call to the AWS REST API with the [`x-amz-copy-source` header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) set. This request would also need to have an [`Authorization` header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) that has read access to the source and write access to the destination. Even if you converted the signed URL to an `Authorization` header, it wouldn't have write access to your destination bucket.